# rxjava : avoid cancelling subscription on error in downstream operations

Tags: rx-java

I am rather new to RxJava, and have a problem for which I cannot find a decent solution, even after hours of research.

Here it is : I am working on a banking application that connects to some server to receive pricing updates, process these updates, and saves them in some internal database. Using RxJava 2, it was pretty easy to get something working when no error happens, but things tend to get ugly if there are errors in the processing stage : the subscription is cancelled, and no more messages are received.

I used to work with an ad-hoc streaming library that simply catches exceptions, logs the errors and messages that caused them, and keeps the stream open. This is a very simple and pragmatic way of handling errors, but it ensured a rather good level of robustness for applications.

Using RxJava2, the only approach that I can think of that would really work is to surround all of my mapping operators by a wrapper that catches these exceptions. It does not feel very robust, as anyone could forget to catch errors, which would lead to the termination of the application.

To hopefully make my case clearer, here is a test that currently fails, and that I would like to fix :

```
@Test
public void shouldKeepProducingWithErrorsInMap() {

    List<Integer> output = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Throwable> errors = new ArrayList<>();
    AtomicInteger startCount = new AtomicInteger(0);

    Observable<Integer> source = Observable.defer(() -> {
        startCount.incrementAndGet();
        return Observable.range(1, 10);
    });

    source
            .map(i -> {
                if (i % 3 == 0) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("I cannot accept multiples of 3, this is " + i);
                }
                return i;
            })
            .subscribe(output::add, errors::add, () -> log.info("done"));

    Assertions.assertThat(startCount.get()).isEqualTo(1);
    Assertions.assertThat(output).containsExactly(1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10);
    Assertions.assertThat(errors).hasSize(0);

}
```

To achieve the right level of robustness, I would like the following:

1. encapsulate the logic of connecting to some arbitrary source, by returning an Observable from some factory method
2. avoid reconnecting to the source in case of errors that happened at some point downstream
3. in case of downstream error, just log the error and move to the next message
4. implement this "source protection" feature in he factory method itself, to avoid interrupting the feed when unexpected errors happen.

Is there a way to achieve this in RxJava2 using available operators, or should I implement a custom operator for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `onErrorReturn` operator ([documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/catch.html)) which lets you emit an element when the upstream observable throws an error. I would have the result object of the observable also encapsulate the state where it fails and emit that object when it fails. Something like.

```
someObservable
    .map(response -> SomeResult.success(action.getMessage()))
    .onErrorReturn(t -> SomeResult.failure(t.getMessage()))
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
// e.g. do something with result, or show toast when it fails.
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.I tried it by adding ".onErrorReturn(e -> -1)" after the map operation. But in that case, the stream is still closed, I get responses "[1, 2, -1]".

Plus, the onErrorReturn operator would need to be added after each map operation, which is not really better than wrapping each map with an exception catcher...

I still hope that there is a better solution out there ;)

Comment: @marc-olivierfleury Sorry, that was a sloppy answer on my part. I'm at work so can't spend to much time on this, but I will come back to this. I think I have a nicer solution.

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer that was given to me is using concatMap, or flatMap (credits to @obogoliy, thanks for the suggestion!):

```
@Test
public void shouldCatchErrorByUsingConcatMap() {
    List<Integer> output = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Throwable> errors = new ArrayList<>();
    AtomicInteger startCount = new AtomicInteger(0);

    Observable<Integer> source = Observable.defer(() -> {
        startCount.incrementAndGet();
        return Observable.range(1, 10);
    });

    source.concatMap(j -> Observable.just(j)
            .map((i) -> {
                if (i % 3 == 0) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("I cannot accept multiples of 3, this is " + i);
                }
                return i;
            }).onErrorResumeNext(e -> {
                log.error("got error", e);
                return Observable.empty();
            }))
            .subscribe(output::add, errors::add, () -> log.info("done"));

    Assertions.assertThat(startCount.get()).isEqualTo(1);
    Assertions.assertThat(output).containsExactly(1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10);
    Assertions.assertThat(errors).hasSize(0);
}
```

This is isolating the portion of the stream that may fail, and using onErrorResumeNext to log the error and drop the message.

It works rather well, the only issue I can see is that this has to be done on the downstream, and there is thus no way send a "robust" source from within the factory class. But doing it would probably imply to break some of the core contracts of rxJava (onError called only once, errors are not swallowed).

If anyone can find something better, I am still buying ;)